# How can I apply a custom sort for a WPF DataGrid from a style?

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have a style that I want to apply to a `DataGrid`.  The `DataGrid` needs to run my custom sort code instead of the default `DataGrid` sort.  The solution that I tried was as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" x:Key="FilteredDataGrid">
    <EventSetter Event="Sorting" Handler="DataGrid_Sorting"/>
</Style>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
private void DataGrid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e) {

    e.Handled = true;

    //Here is where I put the code for my custom sort.

}//DataGrid_Sorting
```

However, this code doesn't build.  It seems to me that because the `DataGrid.Sorting` event is not a `RoutedEvent`, it can't be used in an `EventSetter`.

**How can I customize the sorting for any DataGrid that has my style applied?**

Comment: Typically, you wouldn't sort the `DataGrid` but the `CollectionView` that is bound to the `ItemsSource`

Comment: I don't really accept the question as is. The decision, whether a style is the right place to implement something should be made based on requirements. So what is your actual requirement from a user perspective? Why do you think that a style is the right way to implement it?

Comment: @grek40 I **am** sorting the ItemSource, not the actual rows.  But I want to trigger that sort by clicking the column header, which causes the default sort to happen.

Comment: So basically you need a custom order function per column and you have some subsequent ordering logic when the column has multiple values of the same rank?

Comment: @grek40 No, the collection that the DataGrid is bound to comes from a server and is sorted by the server (we're talking about 1000s of rows in some cases).  I need to make a call to the server to sort the collection.

Why am I using a style?  I have 100s of DataGrids in my project and this style is automatically being applied to ones that have a specific collection type as the ItemSource.  The style does much more besides customize the sort.

Comment: You mean you have something like server-side paging and you need to retrieve different first-N items according to the current sort criteria? The criteria are modified when the user clicks the column header?

Comment: Exactly, that's it.

Comment: Maybe you can react to a click on the column header? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895803/how-do-i-capture-click-events-on-a-datagrid-column-headers

Comment: The problem with that solution is that the DataGrid still tries to sort.  I don't want to set `DataGrid.CanUserSortColumns` to false because I want developers to be able to use that property to disable my custom sort.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191473/discussion-between-grek40-and-nathan-van-dyken).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround to provide a routed event when you only have a "normal" event:

Create an attached property that controls the event forwarding and an attached event that shall replace the original event. In order to do this, create a class `DataGridEx` (whatever class name you prefer) as a container for the attached property (`DataGridEx.EnableSortingEvent`) and event (`DataGridEx.Sorting`).

Also, create a custom `RoutedEventArgs` class that forwards the original sorting event args

```
public class DataGridExSortingEventArgs : RoutedEventArgs
{
    public DataGridExSortingEventArgs(RoutedEvent routedEvent, DataGridSortingEventArgs sourceEventArgs) : base(routedEvent)
    {
        SourceEventArgs = sourceEventArgs;
    }

    public DataGridSortingEventArgs SourceEventArgs { get; set; }
}

public static class DataGridEx
{
    public static bool GetEnableSortingEvent(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(EnableSortingEventProperty);
    }

    public static void SetEnableSortingEvent(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(EnableSortingEventProperty, value);
    }

    // Setting this property to true enables the event forwarding from the DataGrid.Sorting event to the DataGridEx.Sorting RoutedEvent
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableSortingEventProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "EnableSortingEvent",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(DataGridEx),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnEnableSortingChanged)));

    private static void OnEnableSortingChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is DataGrid dg)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                dg.Sorting += Dg_Sorting;
            else
                dg.Sorting -= Dg_Sorting;
        }
    }

    // When DataGrid.Sorting is called and DataGridEx.EnableSortingEvent is true, raise the DataGridEx.Sorting event
    private static void Dg_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is DataGrid dg && GetEnableSortingEvent(dg))
        {
            dg.RaiseEvent(new DataGridExSortingEventArgs(SortingEvent, e));
        }
    }

    // When DataGridEx.EnableSortingEvent is true, the DataGrid.Sorting event will be forwarded to this routed event
    public static readonly RoutedEvent SortingEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "Sorting",
        // only effective on the DataGrid itself
        RoutingStrategy.Direct,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof(DataGridEx));

    public static void AddSortingHandler(DependencyObject d, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        if (d is DataGrid dg)
            dg.AddHandler(SortingEvent, handler);
    }

    public static void RemoveSortingHandler(DependencyObject d, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        if (d is DataGrid dg)
            dg.RemoveHandler(SortingEvent, handler);
    }
}
```

Now use those in your style (with `local` being the xmlns for the namespace where `DataGridEx` is defined):

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="local:DataGridEx.EnableSortingEvent" Value="True"/>
    <EventSetter Event="local:DataGridEx.Sorting" Handler="DataGrid_Sorting"/>
</Style>
```

The handler

```
private void DataGrid_Sorting(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e is DataGridExSortingEventArgs args)
    {
        // will prevent datagrid default sorting
        args.SourceEventArgs.Handled = true;
    }

    // More stuff
}
```

I hope this is what you needed. Had to refresh my memory about attached stuff :)