# WPF DataGrid column header mouse events

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to extend standard `DataGrid` functionality by adding some methods and properties into a derived control:

```
public class ExtendedGrid : DataGrid
{
    ...
}
```

However, handling mouse events of the headers is still unclear to me. Since `DataGridColumnHeader` is not a part of the visual tree (correct me if I mistake), and the only way to set an event handler to the `MouseEvent` is to apply style on it ([How do I capture "Click" events on a DataGrid column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895803/how-do-i-capture-click-events-on-a-datagrid-column-headers)).

Since I'm extending the `DataGrid`, I'd like to keep implementation in code, without adding any XAML, in my opiinion it's inconsistent in terms of code readability. Therefore, I wrote the following code:

```
private void InitializeStyles()
{
    Style headerStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
    headerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnColumnHeaderMouseDown)));
    foreach(var column in Columns)
    {
        column.HeaderStyle = headerStyle;
    }
}
```

This code is called on `AutoGeneratedColumns` and doesn't work well (e.g. at all). Even if it would, it would impose limitations on setting styles on headers.

Is there a way to handle `DataGridColumnHeader` mouse events in my `ExtendedGrid` without any XAML? Or XAML styles is anyway better than search of workarounds (and probably overcomplicationg things)?

Comment: maybe you are looking for the event `GridViewColumnHeader.Click` ?

Comment: Nope, I was looking exactly for MouseDown event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGridColumnHeader` is of course part of the visual tree. It's the `DataGridColumn` and its descendants that are not part of the visual tree as they serve as data objects for the actual rendered `CellTemplate` or `HeaderTemplate`.

Note that since `DataGridColumnHeader` extends `ButtonBase`, you can also execute an `ICommand` that is assigned to `DataGridColumnHeader.Command`.

If you want to execute the same event handler for a certain event e.g., `Click` for each `DataGridColumnHeader` e.g., in order to execute a column based sort, then you can simply register a handler for the routed event directly on the `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid DataGridColumnHeader.Click="SortColumn_OnClick" />
```

or when using a `Style` set the `DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle`:

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
      <EventSetter Event="Click" 
                   Handler="SortColumn_OnClick" />
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

If you are looking for a specific `DataGridColumnHeader` of a column or columns, then traverse the visual tree to find them.
You can get the `DataGridColumnHeader` of a certain column by handling the `DataGrid.Loaded` event:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<DataGrid Loaded="DataGrid_OnLoaded" />
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void DataGrid_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
  foreach (DataGridColumn dataGridColumn in dataGrid.Columns)
  {
    if (TryFindColumnHeader(dataGrid, dataGridColumn.DisplayIndex, out DataGridColumnHeader columnHeader))
    {
      columnHeader.Click += (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show($"Column #{columnHeader.DisplayIndex} Header clicked");
    }
  }
}

public bool TryFindColumnHeader(
  DependencyObject dataGrid,
  int columnIndex,
  out DataGridColumnHeader dataGridColumnHeader)
{
  dataGridColumnHeader = null;

  for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dataGrid); childIndex++)
  {
    DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dataGrid, childIndex);

    if (childElement is DataGridColumnHeader columnHeader && columnHeader.DisplayIndex.Equals(columnIndex))
    {
      dataGridColumnHeader = columnHeader;
      return true;
    }

    if (TryFindColumnHeader(childElement, columnIndex, out dataGridColumnHeader))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: And that's it. By the way, does `DataGrid` initialize these `DataGridColumnHeader`s in the same manner somewhere in its code, so this method could be extended with somethind similar to your answer?

Comment: The `DataGrid` contains a `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter` which generates the `DataGridColumnHeader` elements as its children. There is no such method you could override e.g. to handle events that are related to this process. This are internals. In general there is no need to directly access the `DataGridColumnHeader` containers. To attach commands or event handlers you use styles or event triggers and to customize their appearance you use templates. I styles or event triggers are not an option, you have to dig for the `DataGridColumnHeader` elements yourself.

Comment: You could create an attached behavior and expose this `DataGridColumnHeader` items via attached properties or extend `DataGrid` and add corresponding logic or create an extension method. This is the only way to make this reusable. Just be aware that the `DataGrid` must be loaded in order to have access to the `DataGridColumnHeader` items.